# partially complete vs partially completed

Tags: word-choice

What is the correct – partially complete or partially complete**d**?

I'm using Trello and I want to create a label that says that a card is partially complete(d).

Thank you.

Comment: Either could be correct, depending on exactly how it is being used. Please supply more context.

Comment: Also *{It was] [part complete](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+part+complete%22), [part completed](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+part+completed%22), [partly complete](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+partly+complete%22), and [partly completed.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+partly+completed%22)  I wouldn't single out any of them as either "correct" or "wrong", regardless of possible hyphenation. But ***incomplete*** is shorter, and would often imply something rather different to *not completed **at all***.

Comment: I want to create a Trello label that indicates that a card is not totally complete.

Comment: If you are emphasizing the description (adjective), then it's *complete*; if you are emphasizing the action (verb), then it's *completed*. It's entirely up to you which you want to emphasize.